# How can I create a label in the bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I am working on a check website to validate some information of a users' website. I have a C3JS Chart configured with the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
            var debug = {{ env('APP_DEBUG') }}
            console.log('Debug: ' + debug);

            var chart = c3.generate({
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ['alpha', 100],
                        ['bravo', 100],
                        ['charlie', 50],
                        ['delta', 1],
                    ],
                    colors: {
                        'alpha': '#3FB34F',
                        'bravo': '#3FB34F',
                        'charlie': '#E8B30C',
                        'delta': '#EB370F',
                    },
                    type: 'bar',
                    labels: true,
                },
                bar: {
                    space: 0.05
                },
                axis: {
                    rotated: true
                },
            });
```

This code results in the next chart

[image: chart]

How can I add a label (like alpha, bravo...) in the green/orange/red bar instead of having them on the bottom of the chart?

[image: new]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a solution ready but I could think of two possible solutions.

1. You should be able to create a custom legend like described here: https://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html and then move these labels to the respective bars using translate/transform and D3js.
2. You could try to move the existing labels using D3 and translate/transform.